# VIM auto resize focused window

Tags: vim

I am slowly learning vim and its powerful capabilities.
I have a question in regards to splitting windows (mainly horizontal splits).
Is there a way to automatically resize the currently selected (focused) window? Let's say, for example, a setting so that the focused window will always take up 70% of the screen.

Using <kbd>Ctrl-w</kbd> (number) <kbd>+</kbd>/<kbd>-</kbd> every time is not really efficient, especially when I am jumping between a few files constantly.

Also it would be cool if there was a way to restrict it to only horizontally splitted windows.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The `'winheight'` setting determines the minimal number of lines for the current window. Some users set this to 999 for "Rolodex mode". The following sets this to 70%:

```
:let &winheight = &lines * 7 / 10
```

For anything fancier, you can hook into the `WinEnter` event via an `:autocmd`, and then set the window height to N via `:Nwincmd _`. Stupid example:

```
:autocmd WinEnter * execute winnr() * 2 . 'wincmd _'
```

Comment: is there a way to do the first option but for vertical splits instead of horizontal splits?

Comment: @thepickle: Yes, using `&winwidth` and `&columns` instead.

Answer (score 9):

Sounds like you want [golden-ratio](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3690) : Resize windows automatically using the [Golden Ratio](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golden_ratio).

Once I found out you could disable the "automatic" part of golden-ratio, I started using it myself with these settings:

```
" Don't resize automatically.
let g:golden_ratio_autocommand = 0

" Mnemonic: - is next to =, but instead of resizing equally, all windows are
" resized to focus on the current.
nmap <C-w>- <Plug>(golden_ratio_resize)
" Fill screen with current window.
nnoremap <C-w>+ <C-w><Bar><C-w>_
```

Comment: that sounds quite interesting, I will give it a go.

Comment: Can't say bomb on a plane, but this plugin really is da bomb (y)

Answer (score 4):

I use these mapping for split screens:

```
nnoremap <C-j>  <C-w>j
nnoremap <C-k>  <C-w>k
nnoremap <C-h>  <C-w>h
nnoremap <C-l>  <C-w>l
nnoremap c<C-j> :bel sp new<cr>
nnoremap c<C-k> :abo sp new<cr>
nnoremap c<C-h> :lefta vsp new<cr>
nnoremap c<C-l> :rightb vsp new<cr>
nnoremap g<C-j> <C-w>j<C-w>_
nnoremap g<C-k> <C-w>k<C-w>_
nnoremap g<C-h> <C-w>h<C-w>_
nnoremap g<C-l> <C-w>l<C-w>_
nnoremap d<C-j> <C-w>j<C-w>c
nnoremap d<C-k> <C-w>k<C-w>c
nnoremap d<C-h> <C-w>h<C-w>c
nnoremap d<C-l> <C-w>l<C-w>c
```

This way if you want to jump between splits you can use <kbd>C-hjkl</kbd>. If you want to "create" a split you can use <kbd>c</kbd><kbd>C-hjkl</kbd>. If you want to maximize a split you can use <kbd>g</kbd><kbd>C-hjkl</kbd>. And if you want to delete a split you can use <kbd>d</kbd><kbd>C-hjkl</kbd>.

If you want specifically 70% instead of maximized that you could use

```
nnoremap g<C-j> <C-w>j:let &winheight = &lines * 7 / 10<cr>
```

for example.